# Show in PHP images from Amazon s3 sorted by DATE DESC

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm developing a social website. I'm using **Amazon s3** to store pictures from members. All the pictures are uploaded with hexadecimal prefixes (for performances). I'd like to know if there is a way in **PHP**, to pull all the pictures of the bucket sorted by date of creation (DESC) and with a pagination system, so a moderator or I can eventually easily delete the inappropriate ones.
If you have any idea how I could proceed I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an ideal question for StackOverflow as *you do not have a particular code issue you are trying to troubleshoot*.

That being said, you should be able to do what you want with the [AWS SDK for PHP](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php).

Here is [some documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html) on how to install it -- I would personally advise using Composer.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for you answer. It seems it's not possible, only solution would be to add the date of creation of the picture as a prefix so I can then get the list of objects created with the date of my choice. It's not a perfect solution but it's good enough :-)